# How to make a summarize table reflecting the filtered calculation from visualization filtes/slicers?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm new to Power BI. I have 2 tables ('patient_info' and 'rating_table') which are related to each other 1:1 by the "id" key. I created another summary table ('rating_by_doctor') which groups the ratings among each doctor and calculate the mode for each of them. The DAX expression I used to get the summary table are as follow:

```
rating_by_doctor =
SUMMARIZE(
    rating_table,
    patient_info[doctor],
    "mode",
    MINX(TOPN(1,ADDCOLUMNS(VALUES(rating_table[rating]),"Frequency",CALCULATE(COUNT(rating_table[rating]))),[Frequency],DESC),rating_table[rating])
)
```

[The tables look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1Ztk.png)

However, when I try to add this table into a visualization, and apply a filter/slicer on it (eg: the [gender] column in 'patient_info'), it has no effect to the summary table at all. I want the visualization of the summary table reflects the change of the underlying aggregated calculation based on the current filter/slice, may I know how can I achieve this please?

Comment: Can you share pbix file? It seems, at first glance, your ID numeration is wrong

Comment: please share also the relationship model...